# Unable to install pyautogui. No module named 'pytweening'

Tags: python, pip

When I try to do `pip install pyautogui`, I get this error message:

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\s06elaus\bin\python\python-3.9.0-embed-win32\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\s06elaus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ps6csmue\\pytweening_0ba0040cb36c4fd19bfae435d80ee501\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\s06elaus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-ps6csmue\\pytweening_0ba0040cb36c4fd19bfae435d80ee501\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\s06elaus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-dejgrny5'
         cwd: C:\Users\s06elaus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ps6csmue\pytweening_0ba0040cb36c4fd19bfae435d80ee501\
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\s06elaus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-ps6csmue\pytweening_0ba0040cb36c4fd19bfae435d80ee501\setup.py", line 6, in <module>
        version=__import__('pytweening').__version__, # Dynamically calculate the version based on pytweening.VERSION.
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytweening'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

When I try to install pytweening with pip, I get the same error message.
I
Does anyone know a fix to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go!

```
py -m pip install pyautogui
```

Comment: I am using windows, where it says there shouldn't be any dependencies

Comment: It shows pillow needs to be installed to make it working.

Comment: I have intstalled pillow and it is still showing the same error message